# why OnLongClicked action listener (Method) return a value in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why we have to return a value while using (public boolean onLongClick(View v))
**I need to know about the purpose of returning a value..**
While when we use `(OnClickListener(), public void onClick(View V) )`.
It's void and we return nothing.

Comment: how about reading the documentation? It unexpectedly has the description of what does each method return result is.

Comment: Refer OOPs concepts and syntax. In JAVA, if you add `void` as return type then you don't have to return any value.

Comment: google docs are not very clear to me about this matter, thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `onLongClick()` returned value notify if the callback consumed the long click or not.

It means that if you return `true` your callback will be last who serves the "Long click event", else if you return `false` framework will looks for the next candidate who can serve the event, it can be some View under yours what also has OnClickListener